# Force a connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

My Mysql server instance has crashed (I assume its been 10 hours and its not running) - I have tried `show full processlist` but the new connection can't connect. I've tried using mysqladmin and that can't connect either. I'd really like to not have to reset it because we use replication (master to master) which I'm hoping (pos naively) is still running. Can I somehow force a connection to mysql or access a file somewhere where I can see / kill the bad process?

Additionally if a user already has a connection and the mysql server grinds to a halt is that connection still going to work? I.e. if following this I setup a PHP script which ran on an endless loop with a connection monitoring query times would that work even if the server ground to a halt or would that active connection be affected as well?

Comment: So if I read your question right, the mysql server appears to have crashed and you haven't restarted it but instead are looking for ways to connect to a server that isn't running (properly)?

Comment: Yes if there is anyway. Its Win 2008, I've tried to restart the service but Windows couldn't even do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check if you can start the mysql server again. The replication setup will sync everything and you will be fine.

If one master is down you can only connect to the other one. You may consider using some connection pool with both connections for the app to have a solid failover.